# How to determine current outlook edit recurrence item is a series or an instance in a series using office-js

Tags: office-js, outlook-web-addins

When editing outlook recurrence item ,Outlook web access indicates whether outlook item is single occurrence of a repeating series or the series as following
[image]
[image]
is this `Office.context.mailbox.item.recurrence._isInstance$p$0`
 can be used to distinguish those scenarios using **office-js**   ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `Office.context.mailbox.item.recurrence` is used for that.

The [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/objectmodel/preview-requirement-set/office.context.mailbox.item#nullable-recurrence-recurrence) says:

> Gets or sets the recurrence pattern of an appointment. Gets the recurrence pattern of a 
>   meeting request. Read and compose modes for appointment items. Read
>   mode for meeting request items.
>
> The recurrence property returns a recurrence object for recurring
>   appointments or meetings requests if an item is a series or an
>   instance in a series. null is returned for single appointments and
>   meeting requests of single appointments. undefined is returned for
>   messages that are not meeting requests.
>
> Note: Meeting requests have an itemClass value of
>   IPM.Schedule.Meeting.Request.
>
> Note: If the recurrence object is null, this indicates that the object
>   is a single appointment or a meeting request of a single appointment
>   and NOT a part of a series.

Comment: i added more details to the question for clarification . i actually want to know the recurrence item is a series or an instance in a series

Comment: In case of editing it (Office.context.mailbox.item.recurrence._isInstance$p$0) might work but it is not a recommended solution as per documentation. in case of compose using async APIs are recommended to get the latest info. you can use something like below code snippet: 
Office.context.mailbox.item.recurrence.getAsync(callback);

function callback(asyncResult) {
  var context = asyncResult.context;
  var recurrence = asyncResult.value;
  if (!recurrence) {
    console.log("One-time appointment or meeting");
  } else {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(recurrence));
  }
}